# Windows Waveform Functions - WAVEOUTCAPS for bitdepths other than 8 and 16

Tags: audio, waveout

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms713743(v=vs.85)) for the WAVEOUTCAPS struct lists a number of formats that an audio device can support:

[image]

I do not see any 24-bit variables listed here, although through I have confirmed my sound card is capable of opening a 24-bit output with a call to `WaveOutOpen` (and playing 24bit audio files through that output).

I'm guessing that Microsoft defined additional variables somewhere for 18/20/24/32/48/64 bit output, but I can't find them. I tried searching on the net and nothing came up, and I tried using Visual Studio to search for variables in my current name space that start with "WAVE_FORMAT_" but did not find any additionally defined formats that way.

Is it possible to check for 4/18/20/24/32/48/64 bit output availability on Windows using the function `WaveOutGetDevCap()`, or any similar function? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waveOutXxx` is legacy API you, generally speaking, should not be used nowadays. This API is an emulation layer on top of *real* audio API and does not have to support 24-bit scenarios which did not exist at the time of `waveOutXxx`. There are no specific new constants defined for newer formats and there are so many of them that there cannot be a separate bit for every one.

You can compose a `WAVEFORMATEX` structure that describes your high bitness format (you would typically use `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` variant of it) and check it against `waveOutOpen` function.

Or, rather, use WASAPI and `IAudioClient::Initialize`, see [Rendering a Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/rendering-a-stream) for details and the way `WAVEFORMATEX` structure is used there.